# Unsuccessfully write to file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to write to a binary (*.bin) file and I met a problem.
When I use the following code, it does not write anything to the file:

```
abc = str.encode("sabd")
f=open("sbd.bin",'wb')
f.write(abc)
f.close
```

However, when I use the following code, it works well:

```
abc = str.encode("sabd")
with open("sbd.bin",'wb') as f:
    f.write(abc)
```

I use Win + Python3.

Comment: worket for me on linux, try passing `write` a bytearray, maybe that'll do it

Comment: you need to *call `f.close`*. So use `f.close()`. Better yet, use a `with` statement...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `f.close`, try `f.close()` to see if that works any better since `close()` is a method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest flushing the data to the file, as you are missing this and would cause the file to not be created or written to. e.g. `file.flush()` will create the file if not existent and write the data to it.

source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/file_flush.htm and as suggested by cdlane, close the file with `file.close()` as you are calling a method not getting a variable or something.

Comment: As the link you provided states, "Python automatically flushes the files when closing them", so you don't need to call it yourself in this situation.

Comment: yes, forgot to state that `file.close()` calls `file.flush()`